# How to define global error handler for JSON in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I would like to define an error block (or something) that would return **all** exceptions formatted in JSON somehow **plus** returning the standard http code (e.g. 404 for not found, 303 for auth errors etc).

Something like:

```
error do
  e = env['sinatra.error']
  json :result => 'error', :message => e.message
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the http status code to be included in your JSON object or are you just looking for the status code to be attached to the HTTP response?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

# This is needed for testing, otherwise the default
# error handler kicks in
set :environment, :production

error do
  content_type :json
  status 400 # or whatever

  e = env['sinatra.error']
  {:result => 'error', :message => e.message}.to_json
end

get '/' do
  raise 'hell'
end
```

Test it with curl to see that it works.

Comment: Instead of redefining the environment, you could just disable the error_handler with "set :show_exceptions, false"