# Passing errors list from Sinatra to jQuery's error handler?

Tags: jquery, ruby, error-handling, sinatra, mongoid

I am trying to pass a list of error messages back to my jQuery error handler. Most examples I've read online only have a single error message, but I'm trying to pass back multiple lines.

Here is an example:

```
post "/save/user" do
    user = params["user"]
    email = params["email"]
    age = params["age"]
    user = User.find(user)

    user.update_attributes(email: email, age: age)
    if user.valid?
        user.save!
    else
        run_errors(user.errors.full_messages)
    end

    json :done => "You have updated your profile!"
end
```

Error handling:

```
class MyError < StandardError; end

error MyError do
    content_type :json
    status 500
    {:errors => env['sinatra.error'].message}.to_json
end

def run_errors(errors)
    if not errors.empty?
        raise MyError, errors
    end
end
```

jquery:

```
$(".test").click(function(evn) {
     evn.preventDefault();
     var form = $("form");
     $.post("/save/user", form.serialize(), function(done) {
         console.log(done["done"]);         
     })
     .fail(errors) {
         console.log(errors["errors"]);
     });
});
```

In this example, if a user submits faulty email and age data, Sinatra will fail validations and provide a list of error messages in `user.errors.full_messages`. These would be `Email must be a valid email address` and `Must be over 18 years of age` respectively.

The problem is in the jQuery error event handler. The entire errors list becomes one string instead of a list of error strings:

```
{"errors":"[\"Email must be a valid email address\", \"Must be over 18 years of age\"]"}
```

I could hack the js part and parse the string, but that does not feel like a proper solution. I've tried searching for error handling in Sinatra and had based my findings off [this article](http://hawkins.io/2014/01/delivery_mechanisms-helpers_and_error_handling/) and this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772641/how-to-define-global-error-handler-for-json-in-sinatra), but I'm still not sure if this is how error handling should be done. Both only use one error message too, whereas I need to serve multiple error messages.

My questions are:

- How do I properly pass my error list from Sinatra to jQuery's error handler with my current setup? Or...
- If my error handling logic is not correct, what would be the proper logic of handling errors with multiple error messages from Sinatra to jquery?

Comment: First thing you should change is the http status code, you're using 500 (internal server error) for validation errors based on user input. The correct error code is 400 (bad request). Besides that, can you show us your Ajax call with the error handler which gets triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `Error#message` method which converts your array of strings into a string. A simple solution is to override `initialize` and have a custom `messages` method in your `MyError` class:

```
class MyError < StandardError
  def initialize(messages)
    @messages = messages
    super(messages)
  end

  attr_reader :messages
end
```

Then you can slightly alter your code to call messages instead of message when it is available (you can write something more compact but I want the example to be easily readable):

```
error MyError do
  content_type :json
  status 500
  m = if env['sinatra.error'].respond_to? messages
    env['sinatra.error'].messages
  else
    [ env['sinatra.error'].message ]
  end
  {:errors => m}.to_json
end
```

Note that when there's only one message, I embed it into an array so that the Javascript code can always expect an array with one or more strings inside. You might want to do that differently.